# Which MinGW file to use as a C++ compiler

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, mingw

I have just installed MinGW and in the bin folder I can see 7 .exe files that compile my program:

1. c++.exe
2. g++.exe
3. mingw32-c++.exe
4. mingw32-g++.exe
5. gcc.exe
6. mingw32-gcc.exe
7. mingw32-gcc-4.4.1.exe

My small program (testprog.cpp) compiles correctly with each of them; the `a.exe` file is generated in the bin folder and it runs correctly.

What's the difference between them and which one should I use?
Also, what can I do to change the name of the output file from a.exe to testprog.exe automatically upon each successful compile?

Comment: Which one produces the fastest executable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's quite possible that they are all the same; either exact copies or symbolic links to one another.  Try using the `--version` flag on each to see what you've got.  On my MingGW installation here, each of those binaries differs (checked with `diff`), but they all output the same version information (with the exception of the first bit, which is the filename):

```
gcc.exe (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3)
Copyright (C) 2004 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Use the `-o` flag to change the output file name:

```
gcc -o testprog.exe testprog.cpp
```

Comment: You are right. the first 4 are the same file, as are the last 3. What's the difference though? And thanks for the -o tip.

Comment: @Abbas - the first 4 are C++ compilers and the last 3 are C compilers. They likely have different linking behaviour, as @Crazy Eddie mentioned in his answer. The ones with "++" in their name probably also default to compiling files as C++, even if they have a simple .c extension.

Answer (score 20):

These follow gcc naming conventions.

- c++.exe is a traditional name for the system c++ compiler
- g++.exe and gcc.exe are the names for the gcc compilers that compile for the "current system"
- mingw32-* versions are the names for the compilers that cross-compile to the "mingw" target. In this case this is the same as the system target.
- An then mingw32-gcc-4.1.exe is "gcc for mingw target version 4.1"

You should typically compile C code with a "gcc" variant, and c++ code with a "g++" variant.

Use `-o filename` in order to specify the output filename, the default is a.exe

Answer (score 5):

In unix they'd mostly by symbolic links.  The only major difference is between the 'cc' vs. '++' ones.  You should notice a difference between these two if you use any part of the standard C++ library.  The '++' versions link to that lib automatically.  The 'cc' ones are C compilers and so don't...though you can use them as C++ compilers by just adding -lstdc++ or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

While I was searching around the web for instructions in making some DLLs, I ran into a C++ compilation process that, from what I saw, used g++ to compile c++ the same way as using gcc.

Answer (score 0):

I used "g++.exe"
[image]

Then in my IDE, VSCode, I also had to change the "IntelliSense mode" to "windows-gcc-x64" to get rid of the warning
[image]

Comment: Hey, how is your answer different from others? Would suggest you to edit it so as to make it different.