# c++ command line compilation with gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, windows-7, command-line, mingw

I am trying to use a text editor instead of code::blocks to write some c++ code.  Just wrote a "hello world" program.

My code::blocks ide uses the gcc compiler that I installed, but I want to learn how to do it at a bit of a lower level.  I read a few tutorials that said all I have to do is open a command prompt and type:

```
gcc helloWorld.cpp -o helloWOrld
```

but i get an error saying "gcc" is not a recognized anything.

What do i do to make it work?

Comment: There's nothing particularly "lower level" about running the compiler from the command line, so I wouldn't waste too much time on this... But, the problem is likely that GCC has not been added to your path, so you need to provide an absolute path. Check your IDE settings to see where the executable is actually located.

Comment: Just add a directory containing `gcc.exe` into `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: I assume it's the MinGW version, and you can find an explanation on how to edit your PATH variable on their website. Alternatively, you can use the MinGW (I think it's called MSYS).

Comment: cd into the gcc.exe directory?

Comment: I tried g++ and got the same error.  In terms of adding the path... The path to the main mingw folder is c"\mingw, but there are no exectuables there exept for the uninstall.  I did a search for .exe and there are dozens of them in a whole bunch of subfolders, how do I know which .exe is the actual compiler?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can compile with code:blocks, than probably it ships out with compiler.

You need to find a path to the compiler (probably somewhere in C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks...)
The file name is something like mingw-gcc.exe or mingw-g++.exe
I believe also, that you can find this path in IDE settings.

When you know the path and filename, just add the path to the system PATH variable and call
gccfilename.exe

to compile c++ programms run
g++filename.exe

Also you can run simple compilation without modifying PATH:
just run
"c:\Full path to compiler\compiler.exe"

Comment: Thanks to everyone for quick responses.  When I installed code::blocks, I also installed mingw.  So I think this includes comilers for c and c++.  In the code::blocks settings it has a compiler installation directory of c:\MinGW, so is this the whole path that I would have to specify?  Also,  I did a search for .exe in the mingw file, and there are alot!  how do I know which one is the actual comiler?

Comment: looks like you need folder C:\MinGW\bin
about which file to use look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047798/which-mingw-file-to-use-as-a-c-compiler

Comment: code blocks is a piece of shit software that is broken in Ubuntu, and is 4 versions behind on macOS.  Should use Eclipse instead.

Answer (score 7):

Do `g++ -Wall helloWorld.cpp -o helloWOrld`... for your example

Comment: Are you aware that you answered a question which has been solved 2 years ago with basically the same information?

Answer (score 1):

1. Try installing both the C and C++ compilers - See http://www.gnu.org/software/commoncpp/ etc
2. `.cpp` is C++ so the command line will start g++ not gcc

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, gcc is NOT included in Windows by default.  You have to install it via MinGW, Cygwin, or some other means.

You can play around with MinGW if you like, but I prefer the gcc compiler provided with Cygwin... it's easier for my simple mind to install.  Just install Cygwin and be sure to install gcc as well (it's in the Devel section).

Good luck.